# Wolkenkit - does not start

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, wolkenkit

I have gone through all the steps and actually logged into the boards app from

[wolkenkit-boards](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-boards)

The app starts fine and I can login but the page keeps refreshing at http://local.wolkenkit.io:8080

Has anyone same had the same experience ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the docker containers had to be restarted by running

```
npx wolkenkit start
```

again and then and only then running the frontend. Otherwise if the certificate is added after the backend is already running the backend sees no authentication and the frontend does so it keeps re-rendering.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, and yes – the UX at this point is not optimal 